# How do I bind a property from another project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am writing in C#, WPF application using MVVM pattern.
I am trying to bind a property form different project that I wrote.
While running the the application the property shown but when it updated while running the property is now update.

important to say the in Proj1 the name is updating

```
namespace Proj1
{
  public class Human: inotifypropertychanged
  {
     private string _name;
     public string Name{
                          get{ return _name;}
                          set{ _name = value;
                             OnPropertyChange("Name");}
                       }

     public Human()
     {
        Name = "Danny";
     }

     //implement correctly the inotifypropertychanged

  }
}

namespace Proj2WpfApp
{
  public class MainViewModel: inotifypropertychanged
  {
     private Human human;
     private string _humanName
     public string HumanName{
                          get{ return _humanName;}
                          set{ _humanName = human.Name;
                             OnPropertyChange("HumanName");}
                       }

     public MainViewModel()
     {
        human = new Human();
     }

  //updating the name

  }
}
```

in the xaml code

```
<TextBlock Text ="{binding HumanName}"/>
```

Comment: do you want to use the human Name-Property in the MainViewModel ? I don't get the relationship between the MainViewModel and the Human classes. They only have both implemented a Property called Name

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `HumanName` property doesn't magically change when you set `human.Name`. You also don't update `human.Name` when you set `HumanName`.

You should change your MainViewModel to have a `Human` property instead of `HumanName`:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Human human;
    public Human Human
    {
        get { return human; }
        set
        {
            human = value;
            OnPropertyChange("Human");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

and then bind like this:

```
<TextBlock Text ="{Binding Human.Name}"/>
```

Comment: I'd rather use this composition approach too...